# Function on an array of real numbers that finds out if number in the array is composed for every number in array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, pseudocode

We have a set/array M of real numbers. A number r in M is composed if there are s and t in M with
r = s + t.
The goal is to find an algorithm (in pseudocode) that runs in O(n^2), that decides for every r in M if the r is composed or not. The array is sorted in ascending order.

I have no clue how to find a algorithm in given time complexity.
Thanks in advance for every input given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `O(N^2)` is permissible, you can simply use two loops to check the sums of all pairs. Hash all numbers in a map and decrement their count if a pair is found. If all numbers have 0 count in the end, it means that a sum pair was found for each element. Simple pseudocode would be:

```
def func(array):
    map = {}
    n = len(array)
    result = [false]*n
    for i in array:
        map[i] += 1

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            temp = array[i]+array[j]
            if temp in map and map[temp] > 0:
                map[temp] -= 1

    for i in range(n):
        key = array[i]
        if key in map and map[key] == 0:
            result[i] = true

    return result
```

Comment: So because your using a hash temp in map runs in constant time?
I think that was my problem because i thought that checking if temp in map would run in O(n).

Comment: @MarvinBundschuh Unordered maps generally have O(1) complexity for insert/search/update operations

Comment: I think the code should decide for each number if it is "composed" or not. The only arrays I can think of where _all_ numbers are composed are arrays of 0's.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I think the questions asks to determine whether each number in the array is composite or not. I think the return values of the function should be adjusted.

Comment: @zois the question just mentions checking if each number is composite or not. Unless specified otherwise, a true/false return should suffice

Comment: Based on "decides for every r in M if the r is composed or not" we need to return a mapping of r to a boolean if r is composed. One way of doing this would be to return a boolean array `results` with `results[i] = true iff array[i] is composed`.

Comment: @wLui155 added that